# How to set one resource color value (from ResourceKey) to another (SolidColorBrush)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, c#-4.0, infragistics

I want to set new color to Application.Current.Resources["MainColor"]. I can do it like this: Application.Current.Resources["MainBackgroundColor"] = new SolidColorBrush(color); But I want this color to be from Infragistics.Windows.Ribbon.RibbonBrushKeys

So I want to set value to:

```
Application.Current.Resources["MainColor"]
```

which is definied as:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="MainColor" Color="#FFEAF2FB" />
```

form Infragistics Ribbon resources:

```
public static readonly ResourceKey RibbonGroupCollapsedNormalBorderDarkFillKey;
```

In XAML I would do it for example like that:

```
<Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border1" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static igRibbon:RibbonBrushKeys.RibbonGroupCollapsedNormalBorderDarkFillKey}}"/>
```

But I need to do it in C# codebehind.

I have tried something like:

```
Application.Current.Resources["MainColor"] = Infragistics.Windows.Ribbon.RibbonBrushKeys["RibbonGroupCollapsedNormalBorderDarkFillKey"];
```

But it didn't work. I excepted to get color value from RibbonGroupCollapsedNormalBorderDarkFillKey.

I also tried this:

```
Application.Current.Resources["MainColor"] = Application.Current.Resources["Infragistics.Windows.Ribbon.RibbonBrushKeys.RibbonGroupCollapsedNormalBorderDarkFillKey"];
```

I thought it will change colors, it compiled, but when I click button with this action it changed nothing...

Any help here much appreciated!

Comment: The words *"But it didn't work."* followed by nothing make a lot of people here *very happy*. (<- sarcasm)

Comment: I don't really get what is a problem - before "But it didn't work" I have written what I have tried.

Comment: Describe in detail EXACTLY what you mean by "But it didn't work" otherwise we cannot help you.

Comment: You don't need to know what the problem is you should just explain what the results are, what you expected and if any exceptions or other unwanted behavior occured because of it.

Comment: I have written code (Application.Current.Resources["MainColor"] = Infragistics.Windows.Ribbon.RibbonBrushKeys["RibbonGroupCollapsedNormalBorderDarkFillKey"];) that is not working... isn't it enought?

Comment: No, in general that is not enough. Also see my answer which i updated 5 minutes ago.

Comment: I told you that the key is not a string, it's an object, yet you still try to pass it as a string, above all you try to get it from the application resources which is just one dictionary of many.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RibbonGroupCollapsedNormalBorderDarkFillKey` is a *key*, not a brush.  The brush is in the resource dictionary.  You use the key to retrieve it.

Given that, and given that you're expecting `FindResource("MainColor")` to return a brush and not a color, this should work:

```
Application.Current.Resources["MainColor"] = FindResource(
   Ribbon.RibbonGroupCollapsedNormalBorderDarkFillKey);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked (FindResource(Infragistics.Windows.Ribbon.RibbonBrushKeys.RibbonGroupCollapsedNormalBorderDarkFillKey);)! I just didn't know how to get to this brush.

Answer (score 1):

`Application.Current.Resources["MainColor"] = ...` stores your object in the key `"MainColor"`, if that key **already exists** that is. To add a new resource with that key use `Resources.Add(key,object)`.

Should look like this:

```
Application.Current.Resources.Add("MainColor", Infragistics.Windows.Ribbon.RibbonBrushKeys["RibbonGroupCollapsedNormalBorderDarkFillKey"]);
```

**Edit:** As your resource apparently does exist this is a matter of [casting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx)

```
(Application.Current.Resources["MainColor"] as SolidColorBrush).Color =
     (Infragistics.Windows.Ribbon.RibbonBrushKeys[Infragistics.Windows.Ribbon.RibbonGroupCollapsedNormalBorderDarkFillKey] as SolidColorBrush).Color;
```

You XAML points towards the key being used in the resource hierarchy, depending on where you want to add that key (i.e. code-context) and where the original key is defined you might be able to get the color via `FindResource`:

```
(Application.Current.Resources["MainColor"] as SolidColorBrush).Color =
    (FindResource(Infragistics.Windows.Ribbon.RibbonGroupCollapsedNormalBorderDarkFillKey) as SolidColorBrush).Color;
```

Alternatively you can overwrite the whole brush with a new one which loads its color from your other resource. Note that in both cases this change is done **by value**, if either resource changes the other one is *not* affected.

Comment: I want to set new color to Application.Current.Resources["MainColor"]. I can do it like this: Application.Current.Resources["MainBackgroundColor"] = new SolidColorBrush(color); But I want this color to be from Infragistics.Windows.Ribbon.RibbonBrushKeys

Comment: Your answer do not resolve my problem. I agree that probably this is a matter of casting. I see this problem as how to get color from "RibbonGroupCollapsedNormalBorderDarkFillKey" that I could set to Application.Current.Resources["MainColor"] = new SolidColorBrush(color); in place of "color".

Comment: You need to cast you other resource to something appropriate as well, i omitted that since i don't know what your ribbon resources return.

Comment: I updated my answer, your key should not be a string of the name of the key but the key itself, in my code i assume that this dictionary on the right also returns a SolidColorBrush.

Comment: Added another approach since that dictionary you named does sound fishy, shouldn't it just contain the keys rather than any brushes?

Comment: (Application.Current.Resources["MainColor"] as SolidColorBrush).Color =    (FindResource(Infragistics.Windows.Ribbon.RibbonBrushKeys.RibbonGroupCollapsedNormalBorderDarkFillKey) as SolidColorBrush).Color; I tried it from your approach but my aplication crashed when I run button with action.